# How to judge the value of optind in getopt

Tags: c, linux

I just want to test global variable optind and do the following test.How to judge the value of optind?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char optStr[] = "ab";
    int c;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, optStr)) != -1) {
        printf("optind: %d\n", optind);
        switch (c) {
            case 'a':
                printf("-a\n"); 
                break;
            case 'b':
                printf("-b\n"); 
                break;
            case '?':
                printf("error\n");
                break;
          }
      }

    return 0;
}
```

> ./a.out -ab 
>   optind: 1 
>   -a 
>   optind: 2
>   -b

next:

> ./a.out -a 
>   optind: 2
>   -a

Comment: What do you mean by "judge"?

Comment: @immibis What's the value of optind? Maybe "judge" is not very accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optind` shows the `index` of `next element` to be processed in `argv` array.

---

So, when you do `./a.out -ab`:

When `a` is evaluated, the `next element` to be processed in the `argv` is still `1`, because `b` is not evaluated yet from `argv[1]`.

When `b` is evaluated, the `next element` to be processed in the `argv` is
`2`, because `argv[1]` is completely processed.

---

When you do `./a.out -a`:

When `a` is evaluated, the `next element` to evaluate is `2` because `argv[1]` is completely processed.

---

This is more clearly seen if you increase your options to say. `optstr[] = "abcdef;"`. And call your program as `./a.out -abcdef`. The `optnid` will be `2` only when the last option - i.e. `f` - is evaluated. Also, call `./a.out -a -b -c` to see how `optnid` shows the `next element` to be processed in `argv` array.

Answer (score 5):

The [getopt man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) says:

> The variable optind is the index of the next element to be processed in argv.

And below is how it results in the output you see.

1) `./a.out -ab` will result in `argv` values as such:

```
argv[0]="./a.out"
argv[1]="-ab"
argv[2]=0
```

- Start: `optind`=1
- First `getopt` call: Option `a` is processed and `optind` is not changed. It stays at 1 because the `a` option has been processed but there is still a `b` option remaining.
- Second `getopt` call: Option `b` is processed and now `optind` is set to 2 as there are no more options left in `argv[1]`.

Now for your second example.

2) `./a.out -a` will result in `argv` values as such:

```
argv[0]="./a.out"
argv[1]="-a"
argv[2]=0
```

- Start: `optind`=1
- First `getopt` call: Option `a` is processed and `optind` is set to 2 as there are no more options left in `argv[1]`.